# Check if Youtube video valid? Code Fix

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

ive a database with around 5000 videos and i noticed some of them are removed now.. SO i decided to write a php script to fix bulk check this..
From the various sources below is the code i implemented based on most answers here, but it doesnt give correct results. IT gives a 403 header for 3/4th videos though practically more than 90% are working..Am i missing anything?

```
    foreach ($video as $cat) {  
    $str = explode("=",$cat->videourl);
    $headers = get_headers('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $str[1]);
    if (!strpos($headers[0], '200')) {
    print_r($headers[0].'<br>');
    $i=$i+1;
    print_r("Unpublish".$cat->id. PHP_EOL);
    }
    else{
 print_r("publish".$cat->id. PHP_EOL);
 }
    }
```

I'm printing the header here to debug it, and for most it gives, HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden
Edit :: ive already checked the videoids are passed correctly(so string processing has no issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone trying to achieve this, here is the code.. do appreciate if works for you as ive spend hours to get it working for the new api

```
$headers = checkYoutubeId ($str[1]);
if ($headers == false) {
$i=$i+1;
$db->query('UPDATE `ckf_hdflv_upload` SET `published`="0" Where `id`='.$cat->id);
print_r("Unpublished".$cat->id. PHP_EOL);
}
else{
$db->query('UPDATE `ckf_hdflv_upload` SET `published`="1" Where `id`='.$cat->id);
}
}
}
echo('done'.$i);
function checkYoutubeId($id) {
if (!$data = @file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$id)) return false;
if ($data == "Video not found") return false;
if ($data == "Private video") return false;
return true;
}
```